# jQuery and javascript ('#ID') #update1#helpme

Tags: javascript, jquery

understand me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.deleteMe').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#contributionList').listview('refresh');
});

 $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('#addContribution').click(function () {
               var newAmount = $('#contributionAmount').val();
               if (newAmount) {
                 $('#contributionList').append('<li><a>' + newAmount + '</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>').listview('refresh');
                    $('#contributionAmount').val('');
               } else {
                    alert('Nothing to add');
               } 
     
     });
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="contributionList" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d">
           <li id="l1"><a>5.00</a><a id="1" class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>10.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>15.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>20.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>25.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>50.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>
           <li><a>100.00</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li> 
        </ul>
        <br />
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
           <div class="ui-block-a">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add new Amount" id="contributionAmount" />
           </div>
           <div class="ui-block-b">
             <input type="button" value="Add" id="addContribution"/>
           </div>
        </fieldset>
    
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

^ this code is work in website but when i add it to HTML like this is never work .. i don't know why !

look at the last answer in down someone sent me a link is work !

but when i add it in HTML not work
------- >< >< ><
some people say u don't use $(document).ready(function() {});

and some people say you can use $('ID').on('click',function(){})

^ i did that in my computer it ain't work ! but i didn't test it in website

> <><><----------
>   the problem maybe in my laptop Mac Os X if the code is work then it

should work when i add it in HTML  is not work

basically code work in website but in HTML inside  not work !

Comment: U mean the code is not working??

Comment: Only if we could understand what you are trying to say!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('#addContribution').click(function () {
               var newAmount = $('#contributionAmount').val();
               if (newAmount) {
                    $('#contributionList')
                         .append('<li><a>' + newAmount + '</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>')
                         .listview('refresh');
                    $('#contributionAmount').val('');
               } else {
                    alert('Nothing to add');
               }); 
     });
</script>
```

The script didn't work because the dom element that you are binding ie;'#contributionAmount' is not available when the script is parsed by browser. document.ready event would be compiled by browser once the html dom is ready.

Comment: U can move the script to the bottom of body as well so the elements script is looking for are already ready and available on dom.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your click event inside document.ready event. document.ready event call after DOM is loaded. So when your older script executed DOM is not ready so you can't register your event.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do this jQuery ready event, you can bind a function to an event using `on`, Event Handler Attachment [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```html
<script>
$('#addContribution').on('click',function() {      
    var newAmount = $('#contributionAmount').val();
</script>
```

Comment: i did that to my code it not work :( i don't know why ?!

Answer (score 0):

This code will help as it works fine

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('#addContribution').click(function () {
               var newAmount = $('#contributionAmount').val();
               if (newAmount) {
                 $('#contributionList').append('<li><a>' + newAmount + '</a><a class="deleteMe"></a></li>').listview('refresh');
                    $('#contributionAmount').val('');
               } else {
                    alert('Nothing to add');
               } 
        });
      });
```

check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uiupdates/NXrRp/492/

Comment: bro i took that it work in website but when i add it in HTML it not work jQuery Mobile !